# Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

> Suppose $R= \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{x^5+2x^4+x^2+2x+1}$, then which of the following is true?
>
> 1. The number of ideals in $R$ is 4.
> 2. $R$ has exactly two prime ideals.
> 3. R is an integral domain.
> 4. R[x] is a PID.

I have tried to check if the polynomial $x^5+2x^4+x^2+2x+1$ is reducible. For that, I have checked for roots and then I assumed that the polynomial is reducible and tried to compare the left-hand side and right-hand side of
$x^5+2x^4+x^2+2x+1=(mx^3+ax^2+bx+d)(nx^2+ex+f)$
It seems that the polynomial is irreducible. Is there any general way of checking irreducibility in Finite fields? I know there is an [Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) which is a bit lengthy for this type of problem.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2B2x4%2Bx2%2B2x%2B1+over+GF%283%29) says it's reducible

Comment: That's sad. I'm unable to find any factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a general way of checking irreducibility of polynomials over finite fields. It is called the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) and is based on linear algebra (see your link, which it the Berlekamp–Welch algorithm). For the above polynomial is gives

$$x^5 + 2x^4 + x^2 + 2x + 1=(x^3 + x^2 + 2)(x^2 + x + 2).$$
Your computation is the right way to solve the problem without this algorithm by hand. The only problem seems that, maybe, you did not consider that we have a linear system of equations over $\Bbb F_3$ and not over a field of characteristic zero. So for example $4=1$ for the absolute term.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I forgot to consider 4. So 2 is correct. 1 is false as any ideal containing that quadratic factor has to be a factor of that which cannot happen. 3 and 4 false trivially.

Answer (score 2):

There are only three irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$:
$$
x^2 + 1,
\quad x^2 + x + 2,
\quad x^2 + 2 x + 2
$$
Try to divide your polynomial by each of these.